# Countability of cartesian product of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn)

I have seen analysis books that show  $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is countable by "walking along the diagonals" argument. But I was never quite sure why is this enough, as this does not give a specific rule (or formula) for each element in $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$  (which certainly can be constructed in the first place). I hope this question makes some sense..

Comment: Interpreted properly, "walking along the diagonals" is certainly a good argument. Of course, one needs to formally define a function, but that can be done easily from the idea of "walking along the diagonal." One very easy way of doing this is defining the function recursively.

Comment: It shows that there is a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. In any case, the "walking along diagonals" is easy to write as an explicit formula, e.g., using triangular numbers.

Comment: Duplicates at: [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/bijecting-a-countably-infinite-set-s-and-its-cartesian-product-s-times-s), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective).

Comment: If you want a specific rule $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}[(x+y)^2 + 3x + y]
$

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I just want to make sure I understand this. The picture of "walking along the diagonals" is just motivation for the construction of the pairing function, but by itself does not constitute a proof, right? It is just that I rememmber seeing books that show only the picture and leave it as is, as if the construction of the pairing functions arises trivially to the reader with no second thought..

Comment: Polynomials are nice for some purposes, but there are other ways. There are two interpretations of $\mathbb{N}$, with $0$ and without. Assume without. Then we can map $(x,y)$ to $2^{x-1}(2y-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is an explicit formula for a "walking" function. For some of the details, see the Wikipedia article on the [Cantor pairing function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)

There is a small thing to remember when reading that article. There, as is traditional in logic, one is mapping the set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of **non-negative** integers to the non-negative integers. If you want to map pairs of *positive* integers to the positive integers, that is, if by $\mathbb{N}$ you mean the set of positive integers, let $\pi$ be the pairing function of the Wikipedia article, and define $g(x,y)$ by
$$g(x,y)=\pi(x-1,y-1)+1.$$
We end up with the function
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y-2)(x+y-1)+y.$$
Surprise, a quadratic polynomial!  The fact that it is a polynomial is of some mild usefulness in logic.

Answer (score 1):

The *triangular numbers* $T(n)$ are the numbers that count how many objects there are in "triangular arrays", arrays like $\bullet$, or
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&\bullet\\
\bullet&&\bullet
\end{array}$$
or
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
&&\bullet\\
&\bullet &&\bullet\\
\bullet & &\bullet && \bullet\end{array}$$.

The numbers are:
$$\begin{align*}
T(1) &= 1\\
T(2) &= 1+2 = \frac{2\times 3}{2}\\
T(3) &= 1+2+3 = \frac{3\times 4}{2}\\
&\vdots\\
T(n) &= 1+2+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\end{align*}$$

Given a natural number $k$, there is a largest $m$ such that $T(m)\leq k$, and in that case we have that $k-T(m)\leq m$, since $T(m+1)=T(m)+m+1$.

Going down the diagonals counts triangular numbers. The first diagonal (the top corner) is $T(1)$. If you now add the second diagonal (the pairs $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$) you get $T(2)$; add the third diagonal (consisting of pairs $(1,3)$, $(2,2)$, and $(3,1)$) you get $T(3)$. Etc.

So, given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $m$ be the largest integer such that $T(m)\leq k$. Then we are in the $k$th diagonal. If $r=k-T(m)$, then we've moved $k$ steps down and left. So we define
$$f(k) = \Bigl( r, T(m)-r\Bigr) = \Bigl( k-T(m), 2T(m)-k\Bigr),$$
where $m$ is the largest integer with $T(m)\leq k$.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $k(n) = \lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+8n}-1}{2} \rceil$, and $j(n,k) = \frac{k (k+1)}{2}-n+1$,
then $\beta:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ defined by
$$\beta(n) = (j(n,k(n)), k(n)-j(n,k(n))+1)$$
 is a bijection and 'walks the diagonal'. The inverse $\beta^{-1}: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is given by:
$$ \beta^{-1}(j, l) = \frac{(l+j-1)(l+j)}{2}-j+1$$