# Prove that $N \times N$ is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$|N| = |N \times N|$ ($N \times N$ countable)

I tried to build a bijective function $f(n,m) \to n$. I saw some posts about this question but there wasn't any example nor a good explanation.

Comment: Many good answers and comments (and examples) also at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132831/countability-of-cartesian-product-of-mathbbn-times-mathbbn?noredirect=1&lq=1) and its references.

Comment: What exactly is $N$?

Comment: See [Pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).