# Product (not Cartesian) of sets of reals whose cardinality is $\aleph_0$ is $\aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Defined $X*Y ≡ \{ z\in\mathbb R:\text{ there exist }x\in X , y\in Y\text{ such that }z = xy \}$.

For $|X|,|Y| = \aleph_0$
I have to prove that $|X*Y|=\aleph_0$.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $X,Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$? You obviously have that $X\ast Y$ is infinite, but you also have that $X\times Y\to X\ast Y:(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is a surjection, and so $\#(X\ast Y)\leqslant \#(X\times Y)=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 2):

You have an obvious surjective map $f:X\times Y\to X*Y$. Therefore 
$$|X*Y| \le |X|\times |Y|= \aleph_0.\aleph_0=\aleph_0.$$

On the other hand, for any $y\in Y$, $y\ne 0$ you have a bijection $X\to X*\{y\}$, $x\mapsto xy$. (You know that $Y$ contains a non-zero number, since $|Y|=\aleph_0$, hence you can choose some element $y\in Y\setminus\{0\}$.) Since $X*\{y\}\subseteq X*Y$ you get
$$|X*Y| \ge |X*\{y\}| = |X| = \aleph_0.$$

For the proof of $\aleph_0.\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ see e.g. [Bijecting a countably infinite set $S$ and its cartesian product $S \times S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/bijecting-a-countably-infinite-set-s-and-its-cartesian-product-s-times-s), [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn),
[The cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable) and [Proving the Cantor Pairing Function Bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective)