# Countably Infinite Cartesian Product

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out how to prove this, would you have to start from one side of the proof and move to the other or prove with induction?

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that the cartesian product $A^n = A\times,\dotsc,\times A$ ($n$ times) is countably infinite if $A$ is countably infinite.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Do you know of a theorem that Cartesian product of two countable sets is countable?

Comment: Induction will work, but the case $n=2$ requires non-trivial work, unless you know already that the cartesian product of two countably infinite sets is countably infinite.

Comment: I haven't done much of anything to try to prove it. I have a few notes about cardinality from class, but never on more than two sets in a cartesian product

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is of the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If your notes on two sets in a cartesian product include $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \simeq \Bbb N$, that's all you need.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I'm still not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that $A$ countable $\implies A^n$ countable. If $A$ is countable there is $f : A \to \mathbb N$ injective. We can create a new injection $g : A^n \to \mathbb N^n$ for any $n$, defined $$(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \mapsto (f(a_1), f(a_2), \dots, f(a_n)).$$ To show $A^n$ countable it will suffice to find an injection $h : \mathbb N^n \to \mathbb N$; then the composition $h \circ g$ will give the desired map $A^n \to \mathbb N$.

The famous injective example $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is sometimes called the Cantor pairing function. Rather than duplicating the explanation here I'd refer you to [this Math Stack Exchange thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn) and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). The idea is to represent $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ as a grid, and count the elements, starting at $(0,0)$ and weaving along. (This is the basis for showing $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ are of the same cardinality.)

Now, if $k : \mathbb N\times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is our injection, consider $\hat k : (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ defined 
$((n,m),l) \mapsto k(k(n,m),l)$. The argument extends inductively.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically asking if the equality $|\Bbb N|^n=|\Bbb N|$ holds.

This is true, using the lemma below we have that

$$|\Bbb N^{n+1}|=|\Bbb N^{n}\times\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N^n|\cdot |\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N|\cdot|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N|_\square$$

---

**Lemma.** $|\Bbb N\times \Bbb N|=|\Bbb N|$

Let $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N^2, x\mapsto (x,0)$. This is injective, thus $|\Bbb N|\le |\Bbb N^2|$.

Let $g:\Bbb N^2 \to \Bbb N, (x,y)\mapsto 2^x3^y$, if this is injective, we're done, is it?

Comment: I've used the Cantor-Bernstein theorem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem