# How do I prove that this is onto - f : N → N × N?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My work so far:

I think I need to prove that N x N is either countable or countably infinite.  My first step:

A set A is countably infinite if there is a bijection (1-1 and onto)
function f : N → A.  If a function is bijective, it is also surjective.

Let A represent N x N.  The set N × N = {(n, m) : n, m ∈ N} is countable.

> [image: PROOF of the above statement]

Is this the correct way to prove the original question?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This one is about using the $2^n3^m$ formula, not the diagonal stripes.

Comment: rs479173  Where did you find the proof that you link to?  I.e, Could you site the source?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to construct functions in order to show that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality. A bijection can be constructed, but not by using the correspondence $(n,m)\leftrightarrow2^n3^m$. That correspondence doesn't give us a bijection, because not all integers are represented on the right side, indeed, anything with a prime factor greater than $3$ does not occur here.

One can make a bijection according to the strategy outlined at this MSE question: [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29420/how-does-one-get-the-formula-for-this-bijection-from-mathbbn-times-mathbbn), but that's not really necessary. Another way to show that two sets have equal cardinality is to construct injections in both directions.

An injection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is trivial: $n\mapsto (n,0)$ works, for example. In the other direction, sending $(n,m)\mapsto p^mq^n$ for any primes $p$ and $q$ is great.

Comment: I need to construct a surjection.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @rs479173:  the opposite directions give a surjection.  $(n,0)\to n$ is a surjection, now just send all the other pairs somewhere.

Comment: A surjection from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ could be constructed in the same spirit. Just send any integer of the form $2^n3^m$ to the pair $(n,m)$, and send every other integer to $(0,0)$ or something.