# Let $A$ be finite. Suppose $B$ is countably infinite. Is the set $B^A$ uncountably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A$ be a finite set. Suppose $B$ is countably infinite. Is the set $B^A$ uncountably infinite?

I am new to infinite cardinality arguments, but my initial thinking is *yes*. However, I am uncertain if the claim requires the **Axiom of Choice**... I am concerned that I am using the Axiom of Choice without realizing it, and I would like to *not* invoke the axiom if possible. The following is my pseudo-informal argument.

---

Because $B$ is countably infinite, there exists an injection (possibly bijection) from  $B$ to $\mathbb N$. (i.e. $B \preceq \mathbb N)$. Let $F$ be one such function so that $F:B \xrightarrow{1-1} \mathbb N$.

Knowing that $\mathbb N$ is well-ordered, I can conclude that all subsets of $\mathbb N$ are well-ordered. Thus every member of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ has a minimal element. Further, by Cantor's Diagonal argument $\mathcal P (\mathbb N)$ is uncountably infinite, which implies that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is uncountably infinite as well. I believe a similar argument can be made for $\mathcal P(B)$.

Let $p_{_B}$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal P( B) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$. I know that restricting $F$'s domain to $p_{_B}$ will produce a subset in $\mathbb N$. Call this subset $\mathbb N_{p_B}$. (i.e. $F[p_{_B}]=\mathbb N_{p_B}$)

Let $n_{0}$ be the minimal element of $\mathbb N_{p_B}$. Let $b \in p_{_B}$ be the element that is mapped to through $F^{-1}$...i.e. $F^{-1}(n_0)=b$. Because $F$ is injective, this is unambiguous.

Now, consider the construction of a function $g_{p_B}$. Let $g_{p_B}$ be the function that takes all elements of $A$ and maps them to the $b \in p_{_B}$ that corresponds to minimal element $n_0$ for a given $\mathbb N_{p_B}$. (**This is where I am concerned**...I think I am using a valid invocation of the Axiom of Replacement, but perhaps it is actually the Axiom of Choice)

Because there are an uncountably infinite number of $p_{_B}$'s in  $\mathcal P( B) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, there must necessarily be an uncountably infinite number of $g_{p_B}$'s that satisfy the above definition. The collection of all such functions is a subset of $B^A$. Therefore, if a subset of a given set is uncountably infinite, the set itself must be uncountably infinite.

---

**Edit**

Just to highlight an issue in my reasoning, here is one of my afterthoughts (confirmed by Arturo Magidin):

"Now that you mention it, it does seem like there is necessarily a chance that many of the $g_{p_B}$'s are redundant...i.e. there may be a $p_{_B}\neq p'_{_B}$ that can be represented by the same $g$ function. Perhaps that is an issue as well."

Comment: You’ll need to worry about the possiblity that $A$ is empty or a singleton. Does your argument take that into account?

Comment: Ahhh. Good call on if $A = \emptyset$. Could you please explain what the issue is with $A$ being a singleton, though? Now that you mention it, it does seem like there is necessarily a chance that many of the $g_{p_B}$'s are redundant...i.e. there may be a $p_{_B} \neq p'_{_B}$ that can be represented by the same  $g$ function.   Perhaps that is an issue as well.

Comment: Your process only produces countably many functions. Imagine you have $\mathbb{N}$ itself for $B$, so that you are not worried about your $F$. You say: take a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is not empty; then take its smallest element $p_0$. Then take the function that sends everything to $p_0$. You only get constant functions this way, and there are only $\aleph_0$ constant functions into $\mathbb{N}$. Your error here is that you are not taking into account the possibility that different subsets of $B$ may have the same “least element”, thus leading to the same function.

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between functions $\{\star\}\to B$ and $B$; so you can’t get more than $|B|$ functions if you are mapping from a singleton.

Comment: Yes, iff $|A| > 1$. If $A$ is empty, then $A^B$ is empty (as $B$ is nonempty); if $A$ is a singleton then so is $A^B$.

Comment: Using cardinal numbers, one can look at this the proof that $B^A$ is countable as proving $\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$, which can be done using $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ and induction on $n$. (Or, if you prefer this formulation, you prove first that $|B\times B|=B$ and then you get $|B\times B\times\dots\times B|=|B|$ by induction.) There are several posts where you can find the claim for product of *two* sets: [Bijecting a countably infinite set $S$ and its cartesian product $S \times S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16611), ...

Comment: ... [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29420), [The cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54158) or [Proving the Cantor Pairing Function Bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91318). (And many other posts.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is negative: if $A$ is finite and $B$ is countably infinite then $B^A$ is either finite or countably infinite, and hence is certainly not uncountably infinite. You can prove this by induction on the size $|A|$ of $A$. If $|A| = 0$, then $A$ is empty and $B^A$ comprises the single function $\emptyset$. If $|A|= k + 1$, pick $a_0$ in $A$ and observe that any function $f_0 : A \setminus \{a_0\} \to B$ has only countably many extensions to a function $f : A \to B$ (because we have only countably many choices for $f(a_0)$). By the inductive hypothesis there are only countably many such $f_0$, and then using the fact that $X \times Y$ is countable if both $X$ and $Y$ are, you have that there are at most countably many such $f$.

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick question for you: In your final sentence when you talk of $X$ and $Y$, can I think of $X$ as being the countably infinite set that contains all of the $f_0$ variants and can I think of $Y$ as being the countably infinite set that contains all of the possible $f(a_0)$ assignments?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Awesome. Cheers~~